# SwiftUIのリストで自動的に生まれる要素間スペースを無くす方法

Tags: swift, swift5, swiftui

現在SwiftUIを勉強中の者です。
以下のリストのコードで、各要素と要素の間にスペースが生まれてしまうのですが、このスペースを完全に無くすにはどうしたら良いでしょうか

```swift
struct MainContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            Text("aaa").border(Color.white)
            Text("bbb").border(Color.white)
        }
    }
}
```

上記コードの結果が以下の画像です。aaaとbbbの間にスペースが生まれています。これを無くし、borderが完全に重なるようにしたいです
[image: 上記コードの結果]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結局リストではスペースを無くすことができませんでしたので、別の手段を用いることにしました。

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(values, id: \.id) { data in
                Text("aaa").border(Color.white)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

次のような感じでしょうか。
デフォルトでは最小サイズ以下にRowの高さが縮まらないので`.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)`を指定してセルのTextの高さに合うようにします。

さらにデフォルトでは各セルの上下左右にスペースが入るので、`.listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))`で上下のスペースをゼロにします。`.listRowInsets(()`はリスト内部の各Rowに指定する必要があります。

これでもセパレータのぶんだけ隙間があきます。それもなくしたい場合はセパレータを非表示にするといいです。

```
struct MainContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            Text("aaa").border(Color.black)
                .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))
            Text("bbb").border(Color.black)
                .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))
        }
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
    }
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 記載頂いたコードをそのままコピペしてみましたが、結果は変わりませんでした

Comment: listRowInsetsの各値を適当に変更してみたのですが、どの値も変化はありませんでした。例えばbotomの値を100とかにしてみても、見た目の変化はありません。

Comment: environmentの値を変更したら見た目の変化はありました。ただし０に設定してもスペースは無くなりませんでした